# Removed the default content in nested expression

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am using Pyparsing module and the nestedExpr function in it.

I want to give a delimitter instead of the default whitespace-delimited in the content argument of nestedexpr function.
If I have a text such as the following

> text = "{{Infobox | birth_date = {{birth date and age|mf=yes|1981|1|31}}| birth_place = ((Memphis, Tennessee|Memphis)), ((Tennessee)), U.S.| instrument = ((Beatboxing)), guitar, keyboards, vocalsprint expr.parse| genre = ((Pop music|Pop)), ((contemporary R&B|R&B))| occupation = Actor, businessman, record producer, singer| years_active = 1992–present| label = ((Jive Records|Jive)), ((RCA Records|RCA)), ((Zomba Group of Companies|Zomba))| website = {{URL|xyz.com|Official website}} }}"

When I give `nestedExpr('{{','}}').parseString(text)` I need the output as the following list:

> ['Infobox | birth_date =' ,['birth date and age|mf=yes|1981|1|31'],'| birth_place = ((Memphis, Tennessee|Memphis)), ((Tennessee)), U.S.| instrument = ((Beatboxing)), guitar, keyboards, vocalsprint expr.parse| genre = ((Pop music|Pop)), ((contemporary R&B|R&B))| occupation = Actor, businessman, record producer, singer| years_active = 1992–present| label = ((Jive Records|Jive)), ((RCA Records|RCA)), ((Zomba Group of Companies|Zomba))| website =',[ 'URL|xyz.com|Official website' ]]

How can I give a `','` or `'|'` as the delimmiter instead of the whitespace-delimited characters? I tried giving the characters but it didnt work.